# What kind of regex should i use?

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching, split

i'm trying to split a sentence but **when i put some space left and right side** regex can't split, this is my regex: `\\s*(<>@<>)+\\s*`

My String:

```
hello<>@<>i try!!<>@<>every thing<>@<><>@<>man<>@<>1234567
```

My expected output:

```
hello
i try!!
every thing
man
123456

Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\s*(<>@<>)+\\s*");
pm = pt.split(m);
```

when i try this can't split sentence.

```
hello   <>@<>i try!!  <>@<>   every thing  <>@<><>@<>man <>@<>1234567
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output:

hello\n
i try!!\n
every thing\n
man\n
123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
(\\s*<>@<>\\s*)+
```

**Code:**

```
String str = "hello   <>@<>i try!!  <>@<>   every thing  <>@<><>@<>man <>@<>1234567";
String[] toks = str.split( "(\\s*<>@<>\\s*)+" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf(">>> [%s]%n", tok);

str = "hello<>@<>i try!!<>@<>every thing<>@<><>@<>man<>@<>1234567";
toks = str.split( "(\\s*<>@<>\\s*)+" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf(">>> [%s]%n", tok);
```

**Output (Both the times)**::

```
>>> [hello]
>>> [i try!!]
>>> [every thing]
>>> [man]
>>> [1234567]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to split on either a single space, or `<>@<>`, which can be preceded and/or followed by spaces.

This should perform your split:

```
String[] input = { 
    "hello<>@<>i try!!<>@<>every thing<>@<><>@<>man<>@<>1234567",
    "hello <>@<>i try!! <>@<> every thing <>@<><>@<>man <>@<>1234567" 
};
for (String s: input) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(\\s?<>@<>\\s?)|\\s")));
}
```

**Output**

```
[hello, i, try!!, every, thing, , man, 1234567]
[hello, i, try!!, every, thing, , man, 1234567]
```

**Note**

Notice the empty `String` between `"thing"` and `"man"`, as you have two consecutive delimiters.

Instead of printing the arrays, you can iterate and print each line.

```
for (String s: input) {
    String [] split = s.split("(\\s?<>@<>\\s?)|\\s");
    for (String item: split) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

... will print one item per line.

Comment: when i try this can't split sentence.

hello   <>@<>i try!!  <>@<>   every thing  <>@<><>@<>man <>@<>1234567

Comment: @C.T you'll have to be more specific than that. See output.

Comment: @C.T oh. you change your input **again**. Obvious it doesn't work now.

Comment: My expected output:  hello\n i try!!\n every thing\n man\n 123456

Comment: Yes, that is because I am printing the contents of the array in my output. Not excruciatingly difficult to print each line - see my last edit. The empty `String` stays, you can just sanitize.